# React native video from local file

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, react-native-video, react-native-fs

I am using react-native-video (v 5.0.2) and try to play file from local.

It's working in Android but not working in iOS.

I created the file that I want to play with `react-native-fs`. This is my code:

**Write file:**

```
const localFilePath = `file://${RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}/test.mp4`;
RNFS.writeFile(localFilePath, base64.encode(content), 'base64')
.then(success => {
console.log('FILE WRITTEN');
})
.catch(err => {
console.log('File Write Error: ', err.message);
});
```

**Video source:**

```
source={{ uri: this.state.fileUrl }}
```

I try to change the source with "file://" and without it, with "file:///" and also I tried to use encodeURI.

How can I let it work on iOS?

Comment: Did you try the following? source={require('filename.mp4')}

Comment: any update?? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: @HemendraKhatik not sure it was long time ago, try to do like that: urlFileName = urlFileName.replace(/%20/g, ' '); (if it's working do it only for IOS device).